# An inherent Flash bug with getChildIndex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, debugging, argument-error

I have this code which works perfectly but occasionally - whenever Flash thinks so - it crashes. Here is the debug text produced:

> Error #2025
>
> showResult:true
>
> dolly = 10
>
> Dolly added
>
> Generic Chips added
>
> Highlighting SH:[object SurfaceElement]10-[object TSprite]-vex!
>
> ArgumentError: Error #2025

Note that "vex!" is the name of object *vex*, which is a TSprite (=Sprite).

```
    public function update(players:Array, showResult:Boolean = false):void {
        try {
            var debug:String = "showResult:" + showResult.toString() + "\n";
            debug += "dolly = " + dolly.toString();

            // RESET columns
            columns.length = 0;
            billboards.removeAllChildren();
            var column:ChipColumn;

            // add dolly
            var alfa:Number = 1;
            if (showResult) {
                column = getChipColumn(vex.getChildIndex(numberToSH[dolly]));
                column.addChild(dollySpr);
                alfa = LOSER_ALPHA; // fade-out (non-animated) non-winning columns
            }

            debug += "\nDolly added";

            for (var k:* in players) {
                var player:Player = players[k];
                var bets:Array = player.getBets();
                for (var i:* in bets) {

                    // is there a column already for these chips?
                    column = getChipColumn(i);
                    column.alpha = alfa; // loser..?
                    for (var j:int = bets[i]; j > 0; --j) {
                        var bmp:TBitmap = new TBitmap(chips[k], Align.CENTER, Align.CENTER);
                        bmp.y = - column.numChildren * 5;
                        column.addChild(bmp);
                    }
                }
            }

            debug += "\nGeneric Chips added";

            if (showResult) {
                var shs:Array = SurfaceElement.NumberToAllSH[dolly];
                for each (var sh:SurfaceElement in shs) {
                    debug += "\nHighlighting SH:" + String(sh);
                    debug += sh.corresponds.toString();
                    debug += "-" + String(sh.parent);
                    debug += "-" + String(sh.parent.name);

                    column = getChipColumn(vex.getChildIndex(sh)); // ERROR LINE ?!?
                    column.alpha = 1; // restore alpha
                    column.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xffffff, 1, 12, 12, 3, 3)];
                }
            }

            debug += "\nEnd of Highlighting !!!!!!";

            // sort columns by y
            var sorted:Array = columns.sortOn("sortY", Array.NUMERIC | Array.RETURNINDEXEDARRAY);
            debug += "\n" + sorted.toString();
            for (i in sorted) {
                column = columns[sorted[i]];
                if (!column) break; // pointers to undefined data have arrived (put last)
                billboards.addChild(column);
            }
            debug += "\nEnd of ALL";
        } catch(e:Error) {
            if (!Debug.field.text.length) {
                Debug.field.textColor = 0xffffff;
                Debug.field.appendText(e.message + "\n" + debug + "\n" + e.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    private function getChipColumn(i:int):ChipColumn {
        var column:ChipColumn = columns[i];
        if (!column) {
            column = new ChipColumn();

            // calc column properties
            var sh:SurfaceElement = vex.getChildAt(i) as SurfaceElement;
            var point:Point = sh.getCenterProjected();
            point = billboards.globalToLocal(point);

            column.sortY = sh.center.y;
            column.x = point.x;
            column.y = point.y;
            columns[i] = column;
        }
        return column;
    }
```

From the debugging text, it's obvious that the error happens here:

```
debug += "\nHighlighting SH:" + String(sh);
debug += sh.corresponds.toString();
debug += "-" + String(sh.parent);
debug += "-" + String(sh.parent.name);
column = getChipColumn(vex.getChildIndex(sh)); // ERROR LINE ?!?
```

Error 2025 happens when getChildIndex is called for a non-child object. But *sh* **IS** *vex's* child as the parent's name suggests (vex!). And there is only **ONE** *vex*.

Another peculiar thing is that the error message (*e.message*) simply produces:
**Error 2025**
while error-to-string (*e.toString()*) produces:
**ArgumentError: Error #2025**

Shouldn't it say more like:

*ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller* ??

Comment: It will say that if you run it in the debug player and you see the full stack trace, either in a popup or the console (depending on how you are running it. It looks like your problem is that you have a static method that returns all your shs, and I would be willing to _bet_ that your code is somehow slipping in a sh that is either no longer on the display list or belongs to a different parent, possibly even a different instance that has the same name. Look in the debugger at the memory address of the parent vs. the current vex.

Comment: Well yes, I could as well check if parent == vex, no need to look at hex addresses. I will, and will post my results back here

Comment: Well yes, you were right. I was creating a new "vex" but the static array:
var shs:Array = SurfaceElement.NumberToAllSH[dolly];
contained references to the "old" SurfaceElements that belonged to the old "vex".

One must keep an eye on static references, they aren't destroyed if you don't do it by hand... You may turn your comment into an answer so that I may award it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static global state is a [bad thing](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/). In this case, you have no way of knowing whether or not the sh objects you are retrieving from your static array have anything to do with the current "vex" object or not.

Instead of having `SurfaceElement` track all instances of itself that have been added, consider having your `Vex` Class expose a surfaceElements Array (or better yet, Vector). If these are built on the stage (I suspect you're tracking them statically because you don't have a good "handle" on working with timeline/stage objects), then you could do something like this in your constructor:

```
public var surfaceElements:Array = [];
function Vex() {
    super();
    var loops:int = numChildren;
    for (var i:int=0; i<loops; i++) {
       var surface:SurfaceElement = getChildAt(i) as SurfaceElement;
       if (surface) {
          surfaceElements[surfaceElements.length] = surface;
       }
    }
}
```

Then, when you are done with that specific Vex, you are also done with its surfaceElements with no crossover.